# SQL: Split into the new line same field

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to split into a new line in the same field for sql server statement?
e.g:

```
storage;virtual;servername1, servername2, servername3
```

output is

```
storage; virtual; servername1
storage; virtual; servername2
storage; virtual; servername3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find this tricky, because of the nested split strings.  In SQL Server 2016, this does what you want:

```
select v1.col1, v2.col2, ss.*
from (values ('storage;virtual;servername1, servername2, servername3')
     ) v(str) cross apply
     (values(left(v.str, charindex(';', v.str) - 1),
             stuff(v.str, 1, charindex(';', v.str), '')
            )
     ) v1(col1, rest1) cross apply
     (values(left(v1.rest1, charindex(';', v1.rest1) - 1),
             stuff(v1.rest1, 1, charindex(';', v1.rest1), '')
            )
     ) v2(col2, rest2) cross apply
     string_split(rest2, ',') ss;
```

([Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/19576) is a SQL Fiddle.)

In earlier versions, you can find a split string function on the web pretty easily.

Comment: Bravo thanks...it works for me when using the split string function. Thanks :)

Comment: But how to apply into the existing table e.g: select storage, virtual, servername from tablename?

Comment: @Rindu . . . I'm not sure what you mean by "apply into the existing table".  You can update/insert using a CTE or subquery, so applying the logic for an `update` or `insert` is pretty simple.  Perhaps you should ask another question to clarify.